# How to get the last item of specific type from a list / collection?

Tags: c#, .net, list, collections, outlook

Currently I'm working with Outlook and I'm iterating through a list of items.

Problem here:
I want to ask in the foreach-loop if the current item is the last one - but I can't accomplish this kind of problem.

This is my code:

```
lastAppointmentItem = myAppointmentItems.GetLast();
foreach (Outlook.AppointmentItem myItem in myAppointmentItems)
{
    // Types
    // myAppointmentItems = Outlook.Items
    // myItem = Outlook.AppointmentItem
    if(myItem.Equals(lastAppointmentItem)) { do_something(); }
}
```

When I run the program I get a

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException:
// The last element of the list cannot be called
```

So how can I solve my problem - do you guys know?

Thanks in advance!

Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the System.Linq class to acquire the use of the .Last() method. I have the below example working.

```
namespace StackOverflow
{
   class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         List<Test> tests = new List<Test>()
         {
            new StackOverflow.Test()
            {
                id = "test",
                name = "name"
            },
            new StackOverflow.Test()
            {
                id = "test1",
                name = "name1"
            },
            new StackOverflow.Test()
            {
                id = "test2",
                name = "name2"
            },
        };

        var lastItem = tests.Last();
        foreach(Test test in tests)
        {
            if (test.Equals(lastItem))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("last item has been cycled to");
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();            
      }
   }

   public class Test
   { 
     public string id { get; set; }
     public string name { get; set; }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use "foreach" loop using a "for" loop from 1 to myAppointmentItems. Don't forget to sort it (`myAppointmentItems.Sort(...)`) to have a meaningful order.